# Write byte to ofstream in C++

Tags: c++, file, char, byte

I have char array, and i want to write it to txt file, but in bytes.

```
ofstream sw("C:\\Test.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
  sw << (byte)myArray[i]; 
}
```

This will write chars into the file, but i want to write bytes. If there is char 'a' i want to write '97'. Thank you.

Comment: A `char` is a by definition a byte, so your question is a bit nonsensical, but you probably want `sw.write()`.

Comment: Do you want to write `'9' and '7'` or raw binary byte?

Comment: ofstream sw("C:\\Data\\out.txt",ios::binary);
sw << (byte)97;
sw.close(); This does not work.

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: If there is a 'a' char i want to write '97' to file. No binary, only number 97.

Comment: This code will write 'a' to file.

Comment: But 'a' *is* the byte.   97 is simply the ASCII code for it.

Comment: Yes, i want to write the ASCI code. Solution by scientiaesthete works. EDIT: It doesn't work, for 'í' letter it will write -19. So how to write this correctly ?

Comment: `í` doesn't have an ASCII code, it's not an ASCII character. Are you just trying to print a decimal representation of the values of the bytes in the array or are you interested in the character codes in a particular character encoding like latin-1?

Comment: Character codes in encoding like CP1250.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ofstream sw("C:\\Test.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
  sw << (int)myArray[i]; 
}
```

This will convert a char 'a' to an int(or byte) value 97.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what i looked for. EDIT: It doesn't work, for 'í' it will write -19. So how to write this correctly ?

Comment: @Hlavson: `(int)(unsigned char)mArray[i]`. Probably just `(unsigned char)mArray[i]` also suffices.

Answer (score 13):

To write a byte or a group of bytes using std::fstream or std::ofstream, you use the `write()` function: [std::ostream::write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/)()

```
const int ArraySize = 100;
Byte byteArray[ArraySize] = ...;

std::ofstream file("myFile.data");

if(file)
{
   file.write(&byteArray[0], ArraySize);
   file.write(&moreData, otherSize);
}
```

Comment: Is `uint8_t x = 10; ostream.put(x);` equivalent to `uint8_t* buffer = ...; ostream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), 1)`? Thanks

Comment: I believe so, yes, but I don't normally use `ostream.put()`. Looking at the example implementation of ostream.put(), it does seem to behave identically. (assuming `uint8_t* buffer = &x;` in your example, the results should be identical)

Comment: I don't know about the latest standard, but because `ostream.put()` takes a *char*, it could be implementation-specific whether `char` is signed or unsigned, potentially leading to a bad conversion in *value* with handing `ostream.put()` an uint8_t... but I could be mistaken. Last I checked, GCC defaulted to signed chars, so using `ostream.write()` would perhaps be safer (even though it takes a char pointer, no conversions of values take place with pointers to arbitrary data).